# kotlin : How to make a swipeable stack card view?

Tags: kotlin

I would love to make a function as follow use kotlin :

[image]

I have searched a lot online ,but I couldn't find the kotlin edition .

Anyone know how to make it with kotlin,available swipe left right top bottom ?

If yes , please share with me a Demo .

Thank you so much in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [this](https://github.com/yuyakaido/CardStackView).

[Here](https://reposhub.com/android/cardview/yuyakaido-CardStackView.html) shows the example to how to use this